# Meteor subscribe and publish permissions for indirect parameters

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I am building a family tree and using a collection with people that denotes parents as an object with an array of the two id's as such `{ id: 1, name: "John Doe", parents: [3,4] }` and can find ascendants and descendants.  This collection could have thousands of people not related to each other so...

I only want to publish and automatically subscribe to only:

1 - direct ascendants and descendants (infinite levels)
2 - siblings (full and half) plus 1 level above and below from them
3 - uncles/aunts plus 1 level above and below from them

Additionally if I want to allow 2 levels from any of these )incase someone wants to browse siblings of a great grandfather for example) how would I do that?  I have only used the very based of publish/subscribe and looked over the documentation but don't see how I can implement this.

Comment: https://github.com/svasva/meteor-publish-with-relations

Comment: @Sindis:  Cool find.  I'd suggest putting it as an Answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: Ok. I added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/svasva/meteor-publish-with-relations is a package to easily create relations between collections

To avoid meteorite you can add it like

```
meteor add mrt:publish-with-relations
```